# How to say "outing" in non LGBTQ terms?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to say that personal conversations sometimes feels like "outing" yourself because you're exposing little parts of you that you don't want others to hear. I understand that outing is associated with coming out of the closet, but I'm not trying say that.

I sometimes feel like I'm _____ myself when I carry my pink Hello Kitty purse.
I feel like I'm publicly ____ everytime I ask questions at work.

Is there another word other than "exposing"?

Comment: I don’t feel like this is a niche term, so I don’t understand what’s wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like *outing* or *exposing*, maybe you'll like *revealing*.

> **Revealing (adj):** allowing a look at or an understanding of something inner or hidden
> a revealing confession
> also: tending to expose more typically hidden parts of the body.
>
> [[Merriam Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revealing)

Comment: It's OK to use 'outing' in connection with revelations that are not about sexual orientation, if you specify what is being revealed, e.g. outed as a socialist.